# Dynamic variable in Twig, example?

Tags: twig

I don't quite understand how the attribute function in Twig works. Can somebody help me with an example?

I have a field in a SQL that is named dynamic. I could be eg "field27", but I don't know the number, the number is saved in radio.id. I would like to do someting like this:

```
{% for radio in gruppeType.radios %}
<td><!-- value of "field" + radio.id--></td>
{% endfor %}
```

How can I use field + radio.id as the name of the twig-variable?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can build the field name with a variable, then use it in the [attribute function](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/attribute.html) to access the data within the object/array. As example:

```
{% set fieldName = "field" ~ radio.id %}

{{ attribute(gruppeType, fieldName) }}
```

A working example can be seen in [this twigfiddle](http://twigfiddle.com/g2bcem)

Hope this helps.