# Fixed array name to Dynamic

Tags: twig

I would like to change a fixed array name to a dynamic array name.
Within a

```
set item_classes = [
          item.original_link.nid and item.original_link.p6 and item.original_link.in_active_trail ? 'active',
        ]
```

This works because the 'nid' and p6 are the same and unique.

Within the **item.original_link** array there are 19 values:

```
'nid' => string(3) "114" - Node ID
'bid' => string(3) "100"
'pid' => string(3) "111"
'has_children' => string(1) "0"
'weight' => string(1) "0"
'depth' => string(1) "3" - Page Depth
'p1' => string(3) "100"
'p2' => string(3) "111"
'p3' => string(3) "114" - P+Depth
'p4' => string(1) "0"
'p5' => string(1) "0"
'p6' => string(1) "0"
'p7' => string(1) "0"
'p8' => string(1) "0"
'p9' => string(1) "0"
'in_active_trail' => boolTRUE
'access' => boolTRUE
'title' => string(21) "Development.twig.html"
'options' => array(0)
```

I need to set the value of the **item.original_link.p6** to a dynamic value of: 'p + depth'.

As in this example, the value would be **item.original_link.p3**.

I hope I have explained this in enough detail for someone to help or give me direction.

I have added a **set** variable as below:

```
        {% set my_var = [ ('p' ~ item.original_link.depth ), ] %}
```

This gives me the desired dynamic variable, but when I use this in the next **set** as below:

```
        {% set item_classes = [ item.original_link.nid and item.original_link.my_var and item.original_link.in_active_trail ? 'is_active', ] %}
```

it returns NULL

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dynamic variable in Twig, example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40177195/dynamic-variable-in-twig-example)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I don't know how to reference my variable, **my_var**, using the attribute within the statement.I have added a **set** variable as below:

`twig
        {% set my_var = [
          ('p' ~ item.original_link.depth ),
        ] %}

`

This gives me the desired dynamic variable, but when I use this in the next **set** as below:
`twig
        {% set item_classes = [
          item.original_link.nid and item.original_link.my_var and item.original_link.in_active_trail ? 'is_active' : 'not_active',
        ] %}
`
it returns **NULL**.

Comment: Did you actually read the answer in there? U'd need to use `attribute(item.original_link, my_var)` now you are trying to reference the property `my_var` which is indeed non-existenced

Comment: Sorry. Yes I did read the suggestion and after some trial and error I user this 

`item.original_link.nid and attribute(item.original_link, my_var) and item.original_link.in_active_trail ? 'is_active',`

which is exactly what you have in your comment.

Many thanks